# VLC Streaming - how to support time seek in player?

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlc, http-streaming

I have found standart command line for HTTP streaming with VLC:

```
vlc -vvv 1.mov --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=127.0.0.1:8181}"
```

But this command line's options allow only simple streaming, without time seek in clients player. Is it possible to stream video with time seek in player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seek commands can be issued via the putty session e.g.

so connect to it first e.g.

```
add videopath\video.ts
```

then

```
seek 85%
```